# Editing Class methods def self.xxx

Tags: ruby, rspec, class-method, test-first

If I am editing the Array class, shouldn't I have to define each method with a self (e.g. `self.sum`). I'm not sure why this passes the rpsec tests for the 'Test-First' Ruby track without the self.method immediately following the def.

```
class Array

  def sum
    count = 0
    self.each {|x| count += x}
    count
  end

  def square
    self.map {|x| x * x}
  end

  def square!
    self.map! {|x| x * x}
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the Test-First RSpec test?

Comment: By the way: you can write `sum` shorter: `def sum; reduce(&:+); end`. Also `self.` before `map`,`map!`, and `each` is not needed.

Comment: i think the OP refers to the [Learn ruby Test-First course](https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby). Don't know which lesson he tries to solve, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "instance methods" - they operate on an *instance* of an `Array`, not the `Array` class itself. If you were to put `self.` before the name of each method when defining it, you would be defining a "class method", which wouldn't make any sense for these methods.

Although not necessary, the reason that `self.` works when *invoking* these methods from within the body of another one of the methods is that `self` is defined to be the "instance" at that point. This contrasts to when you're *defining* the methods with `def`, where `self` is the `Array` class.